# Solaris 10 inside KVM (Ubuntu 14.04) - network card not working

Tags: ubuntu, networking, kvm-virtualization, solaris, solaris-10

I have a problem with getting network running on a Solaris 10 guest running on a Ubuntu 14.04 kvm host.

Installation of the guest runs fine but I can get no network connectivity from the guest to the outside world.

This is the network device definition inside the kvm guest definition:

```
<interface type='bridge'>
  <mac address='52:54:00:d6:fc:e7'/>
  <source bridge='br1'/>
  <model type='e1000'/>
  <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x0'/>
</interface>
```

The device is recognised inside the Solaris guest but either a dhcp request is answered then I can get a connection using a static IP address.

I've tried other models for the network interface but they didn't work either.

To be honest, I have no idea where to start debugging this problem. Any help would be appreciate.

Thanks in advance for any help.

P.S. Other guests (e.g. Ubuntu guest) doesn't have this problem. Everything runs well.

Answer (score 1):

I think you ran into this bug:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/qemu/+bug/1395217

The bug describes that qemu 2.0.0 and up has a compatibility issue with networking on OpenSolaris and will not work.  It was reported in November 2014.

Disabling the x2apic feature makes the network card working again. See for a detailed working configuration this bug report:
https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1262093